# Идентификация пользователя

Tags: php, cookie, codeigniter, сессия

Здравствуйте! Пишу интернет-магазин на CodeIgniter, т.к. встроенная корзина так и не заработала, пишу корзину сам. Соответственно, при заходе на сайт, я создаю куки для пользователя, с его IP, таким образом:

```
$this->input->set_cookie('user',$this->input->ip_address(),860000);
```

Куки создаются на стороне клиента я так понимаю. Дальше я добавляю товар в корзину, данные хранятся в БД. Туда попадает IP-адрес в поле user, используя:

```
$this->input->cookie('user');
```

И дальше мне нужно вывести корзину этого пользователя, тут то и возникает проблема, я захожу с разных устройств, браузеров, но вижу одну и ту же корзину, то есть условие where не выполняется:

```
public function get_items() {
    return $this->db->where('user',$this->input->cookie('user'))->get('cart')->result_array();
}
```

Почему так происходит? Ощущение что эти куки хранятся на стороне сервера.

Comment: а чем класс корзины CodeIgniter не устроил?
там все понятно и если что под нужды свои поправить нет проблем

Comment: Дело в том что он просто не добавлял товары в корзину. Я искал проблему, находил, правил библиотеку. но $this->cart->insert(); всегда вызывал FALSE

Comment: Даже тупо из документации копировал код, всё-равно не удавалось добавить товар в корзину.

Comment: " я захожу с разных устройств, браузеров, но вижу одну и ту же корзину" А пробовали с разных IP?

Comment: Ну да, я заходил с разных устройств, у которых разный IP

Comment: @chuikoff, разный IP - понятие растяжимое. Уж не из-под NAT-а какого-нибудь все эти разные устройства ломились на сайт?  
*Ощущение такое, что пара человек из одной сети сойдут с ума при попытке у вас что-то купить :)*